# how to change img src attribute as it's parent select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [this](https://codepen.io/benfrain/pen/peepXO) code for my carousel, I want to change `src` attribute of an `<img>` tag base on it's parent `"aria-selected"` attribute set it to "true" manually.

```
$(".item").on('click',function(event){
 $(this).parent('a').attr("aria-selected","true")
}
```

How can I achieve this, with javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correclty you want to get the image element in the current `item` scope and replace its `src`. So something like this should work:

```
links.forEach(function(item) {
    item.setAttribute("aria-selected", "false");
    var image = item.querySelector('img');
    var currentSrc = image.getAttribute('src');
    var newSrc = currentSrc.replace('.png', '-active.png');
    image.setAttribute('src', newSrc);
});
```

Comment: Thank @LazerBass, I inspired by your suggestion and do this as following code.